# Wordpress/Woocommerce : How to display the content of the different sections of ''my-account'' in custom locations?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display the content of the different sections found in my-account page (woocommerce) in custom locations. Basically I am trying to create a pop up with an accordion menu in it and for each menu I want to have the different sections of the My-account page, my accordion would be like this :

```
My Orders                +
My shipping address      +
My Account details       +
Logout                   +
```

I have already found a piece of code in this website to display the content of an entire page using its post ID, and it works great but this code won't work for me because only the my account page has a post ID and not the section within that page: orders, account details, shipping address ect.. Those sections only have URLs

[My Account page Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMKay.png)

Comment: Either create menu with endpoints or built your accordion with those endpoints - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-endpoints-2-1/

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry, but SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. You should consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rewriting your question to include some coding you've tried to show that you have put in a little effort before you came here.  -- For what it's worth, there are several hooks for the WooCommerce My Account page so that you can do this.

Comment: Hi Martin , but if I create a menu with endpoint the customer will go to another page and I want him to be able to access all the information through the accordion menu inside a pop up